# Select and copy part of the text from a link in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra, copy-paste

How can I copy only a section of text from a hyper link?

As in, if there is a link like below, how can I copy only  a part of the text that is linked?

> [Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation.](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-h/2701-h.htm)

I want to copy *only* the "nothing particular" words from the above text.

How could I do that?

On Chrome I had an extension that let me select links like normal text by holding shift.

I hope there is a similar way for me to select the text of a link in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started using Tampermonkey so ported my tiny extension to a user script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Shift to select link text
// @version      1.0
// @description  Hold down the shift key to select text from within hyperlinks
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';

  function bindNewAnchor(element) {
    element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
      if (element.innerText) {
        if (event.shiftKey) setContenteditable(this);
        currentElement = this;
      }
    });
    element.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 67 && event.metaKey) {
        document.execCommand('copy');
      }
    });
    element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
      this.removeAttribute("contenteditable");
      currentElement = null;
    });
    element.addEventListener("keypress", blockEvent);
    element.addEventListener("paste", blockEvent);
    element.addEventListener("cut", blockEvent);
    allNodes.push(element);
  }

  function blockEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function setContenteditable(element) {
    element.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    if (window.getComputedStyle(element, null).outlineWidth == "0px") {
      element.style.outlineWidth = "0px";
    }
  }

  var currentElement = null, allNodes = [];

  addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
    if (allNodes.indexOf(event.target) == -1 && event.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement) {
      bindNewAnchor(event.target);
    }
    if (event.target.querySelectorAll) {
      var element = event.target.querySelectorAll("a");
      for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        if (0 > allNodes.indexOf(element[i])) bindNewAnchor(element[i]);
      }
    }
  });

  for (var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a"), i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) bindNewAnchor(elements[i]);

  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (currentElement && event.keyCode == 16) {
      setContenteditable(currentElement);
    }
  });
})();
```

Hold shift and drag over links to select them.

Comment: If you used the `Option ⌥` instead this would bring it up to par with Chrome and Firefox (and `Alt` on Windows, `Super`+`Alt` on Linux).

Comment: Just change `event.keyCode == 16` to `event.keyCode == 18` to use the `Option` key. (also, probably obvious, but you can use the Safari free Userscripts ext with his same code too)

Answer (score 2):

In Safari this is not directly possible and I do not know a special extension for that.

A workaround:

start selecting the text *behind* "circulation",
stop at "nothing", (that selects as plain text and starts your selection  at the relevant bit)
now <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

paste where you like

jump to beginning of paragraph
jump two words forward
delete the rest (quick way for that, just not on SE: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> *or* <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrows</kbd>)

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to just copy the whole thing, paste it into a TextEdit document, convert to plain text, and then copy out exactly what you want.