# How to select part of the text of a link in Safari 14.0 on macOS 10.15.7

Tags: macos, safari

I asked a very similar question before: [Select and copy part of the text from a link in Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/320080/150109)

How can I copy only a section of text from a hyper link? For example in google results:

[image]

How can I copy "Inosuke Hashibira" from that link?

Previously, the only solution was to use a custom extension or userscript.

Now two years have passed, and I can't figure out how to add custom extensions anymore. I also don't really want to go through all the trouble of installing a userscript manager just for this, especially since Safari's not very friendly to extension developers and often breaks them every update, and (probably because of this) developers don't seem to care for supporting Safari.

How can I select part of a link in Safari nowadays?

Comment: Best I could do was select only **Inosuke Hashibira | Kimetsu no Yaiba Wikia | Fandom** and press **⌘C**, then paste it elsewhere and delete everything but **Inosuke Hashibira**.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most eloquent way of doing it but still delivers results without any extension.

Hover over link, open contextual menu (two finger press), select 'Inspect Element' (this will open split window and land you on selected element),
[image]

double click on text between span tags (to make text field 'active'), copy needed part of text, close split window.

[image]